# How to fix this TypeError?

Tags: python, typeerror, project

I get this error: `TypeError: clear() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

from this bit of code as far as I know:

```
  def drawHUD(self,score):
    self.hud.clear()
    self.hud.color("white")
    self.hud.penup()
    self.hud.hideturtle()
    self.hud.goto(0, -400)
```

I'm not really sure what to do. I'm expecting it to collide with the fruit and then grow longer and the fruit appears elsewhere

Comment: Surely this is in a class somewhere?  What's your class declaration look like?  There's six places where this parameter could be missing just from this method declaration alone.

Comment: Post the complete traceback.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the call to `clear` expects to be given an argument. In your call to `clear` you dont pass any.

You should take a look at its documentation and/or its declaration.